# Differential equations of the form $y' = a+by$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $f(x)$ satisfies the diff equation $f'(x) = a + bf(x)$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

(a) Solve the diff equation by substituting $u(x) = a + bf(x)$ and solving the simpler diff equation that results for $u(x)$.

(b) Solve the initial value problem:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = a + by$, with $y(0) = y_0.$

Please go step by step and explain! I am a beginner.

No integration allowed!

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly have you stuck?

Comment: This is what I have done: u(x) = e^kx. Other than that I am stuck.

Comment: That is the general solution. What is the simpler diff equation I am supposed to solve?

Comment: u(x)=a+bf(x). u(x)=Ce^kx. From those two we get -> Ce^kx=a+bf(x) or f(x)=Ce^kx-a/b. In the solution section of the book it says that it is f(x)=Ce^bx-a/b. Why b at the ...e^bx... part?

Comment: I suppose in (a) that  for solving the equation $u'(x) = bu(x)$ you indirectly use the integration: $\int 1/x dx $. So, why did you say that integration is not allowed?

Comment: Because it is in a chapter that is before integration so basically at this point we don't know how to integrate.

Comment: So, you can consider that the solution is in the form $Ce^{kx}$ and substitute in your differential equation.

Comment: How do we find what k is?

Comment: $k$ is obtained from $u'(x) = bu(x)$.

Comment: Can you please show me? I don't get it :( Why is f(x)=u(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)**: If $u(x) = a + b f(x)$, then $u'(x) = b f'(x)$. Thus we are solving

$u' = b u$,

meaning $u(x) = Ce^{bx}$. This means

$a + b f(x) = Ce^{bx}$

Rearrange to get

$f(x) = \frac{1}{b} (Ce^{bx} - a)$.

For **(b)**, we want $f(0) = y_0$, some initial value.

$\implies y_0 = \frac{1}{b}(C - a)$

which cannot be solved further without extra information.

Comment: I realised I missed a factor of b as soon as I posted. Fixed.

Comment: Thus we are solving

u′=bu, How did you get there? Why is f'(x)=u(x)

Comment: Let $u(x) = a + b f(x)$, then take the derivative of both sides. The constant term $a$ vanishes and we just get the derivative of $b f(x)$, which is $b f'(x)$. So $f' = \frac{1}{b} u'$, and we substitute this into the LHS of the original eqn. to get $\frac{1}{b} u' = u$.